# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode

Tags: python, file, encoding, decoding, representation

I'm reading a file that contains Romanian words in Python with file.readline().
I've got problem with many characters because of encoding.

Example :

```
>>> a = "aberație"  #type 'str'
>>> a -> 'abera\xc8\x9bie'
>>> print sys.stdin.encoding
UTF-8
```

I've tried encode() with utf-8, cp500 etc, but it doesn't work.

I can't find which is the right Character encoding I have to use ?

thanks in advance.

Edit: The aim is to store the word from file in a dictionnary, and when printing it, to obtain aberație and not 'abera\xc8\x9bie'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What are you trying to do?

This is a set of bytes:

```
BYTES = 'abera\xc8\x9bie'
```

It's a set of bytes which represents a `utf-8` encoding of the string "aberație". You *decode* the bytes to get your unicode string:

```
>>> BYTES 
'abera\xc8\x9bie'
>>> print BYTES 
aberaÈ›ie
>>> abberation = BYTES.decode('utf-8')
>>> abberation 
u'abera\u021bie'
>>> print abberation 
aberație
```

If you want to store the unicode string to a file, then you have to *encode* it to a particular byte format of your choosing:

```
>>> abberation.encode('utf-8')
'abera\xc8\x9bie'
>>> abberation.encode('utf-16')
'\xff\xfea\x00b\x00e\x00r\x00a\x00\x1b\x02i\x00e\x00'
```