# Using python opencv to load image from zip

Tags: python, opencv

I am able to successfully load an image from a zip:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'r') as zfile:
    data = zfile.read('test.jpg')
    # how to open this using imread or imdecode?
```

The question is: how can I open this using imread or imdecode for further processing in opencv without saving the image first?

**Update:**

Here the expected errors I get.  I need to convert 'data' into a type that can be consumed by opencv.

```
data = zfile.read('test.jpg')
buf = StringIO.StringIO(data)
im = cv2.imdecode(buf, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
# results in error: TypeError: buf is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

a = np.asarray(buf)
cv2.imdecode(a, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
# results in error: TypeError: buf data type = 17 is not supported
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

use [`numpy.frombuffer()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) to create a uint8 array from the string:

```
import zipfile
import cv2
import numpy as np

with zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'r') as zfile:
    data = zfile.read('test.jpg')

img = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(data, np.uint8), 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

[HYRY's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21357377/2419207) does indeed provide the most elegant solution

---

Reading images in Python doesn't quite comply with ["There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

It is possible that sometimes you'd rather avoid using [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) in some parts of your application. And use [`Pillow`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.3.0) or [`imread`](https://github.com/luispedro/imread) instead. If one day you find yourself in such situation, then hopefully following code snippet will be of some use:

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'r') as zfile:
    data = zfile.read('test.jpg')

# Pillow
from PIL import Image
from StringIO import StringIO
import numpy as np
filelike_buffer = StringIO(data)
pil_image = Image.open(filelike_buffer)
np_im_array_from_pil = np.asarray(pil_image)
print type(np_im_array_from_pil), np_im_array_from_pil.shape
# <type 'numpy.ndarray'> (348, 500, 3)

# imread
from imread import imread_from_blob
np_im_array = imread_from_blob(data, "jpg")
print type(np_im_array), np_im_array.shape
# <type 'numpy.ndarray'> (348, 500, 3)
```

Answer to ["How to read raw png from an array in python opencv?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11601466/2419207) provides similar solution.

Comment: oh, noes, that'll try to make an unicode string of something, that's actually a byte array

Comment: @berak you may want to check out answer to ["UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6541289/2419207)