# Reading video from a zipped folder in Python

Tags: python, opencv, zip, video-capture

I am trying to read several **.mp4** videos from a **.zip** folder for further processing. Trying to used **zipfile** and **OpenCV** like this:

```
zf = ZipFile(video_zip_loc)
all_files = zf.namelist()
video_file = zf.read(all_files[0])

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file)
```

But get the following error

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)
```

Also attempted to use

```
np.frombuffer(video_file, np.uint8)
```

As suggested here: [Using python opencv to load image from zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357184/using-python-opencv-to-load-image-from-zip). This returns a 1D array and I am not sure how to convert it into a sequence of images. If I try sticking it into VideoCapture get the following error:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Is there a solution to this? Or should I just unzip all the videos first? (Several GB of data...)

Comment: `cv2.VideoCapture` requires a file name as input argument.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: As far as I know there is no solution using OpenCV. There is a solution using FFmpeg, but it's a complicated solution. I think you better unzip all the videos first.